# java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]

Tags: spring

There are quiet a few posts here regarding this issue, however none of them contained a solution for my problem.

```
Caused by:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]
       at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
```

What does `[/<NONE>]` represent?

Comment: can you share your `web.xml` file.

Comment: I am trying but when i try to confirm my changes I am prevented as my post is mostly code? Any solution?

Comment: Add the full stacktrace not a snippet. I know what the problem is, ran into this when preparing a demo (never update dependencies before a demo :) )... To workaround the issue see https://github.com/Conspect/conspect-legacy/tree/master/lab2#modify-bookstore-to-use-config-server-without-spring-boot (point 3 especially the note in that point).